# declare variables with $this keyword inside mouseover/mouseout events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following working without an issue. But I like to know what is the best way to declare variables, using `$this`, only once instead of repeating it twice.

```
$('table tr td').mouseover(function(){

  var index = $(this).index() + 1,
  allColumn = $('table tr td:nth-child('+ index +')');

  allColumn.addClass('highlight');

});

$('table.data tr td').mouseout(function(){

  var index = $(this).index() + 1,
  allColumn = $('table tr td:nth-child('+ index +')');

  allColumn.removeClass('highlight');

});
```

Comment: you mean `$this` from php?

Comment: $this as jQuery selector, in this case $('table tr td').

Comment: @david OP means using a variable named `$this` usually set to a jQuery object wrapping whatever the `this` keyword refers, in OP's case the element that triggered the event.

Comment: Your particular code really wouldn't benefit from caching `$(this)` to a variable as you only use it once. If you used it more than once then yes you would want to cache it. Also you wouldn't be able to cache it for use in both of the callbacks as `this` will more than likely refer to a different a element different times.

Comment: you can write both your events as one, and still you can optimize your code. In approximately 1/3rd lines you can finish writing what you have written here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way is attach all the events using single `on` method and there declare the variables and check for the event type. Then do add or remove class

```js
$('table.data tr td').on('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
  
    index = $(this).index() + 1,
    allColumn = $('table tr td:nth-child(' + index + ')');
  if (e.type === 'mouseover') {  // type of event
    allColumn.addClass('highlight');

  } else if (e.type === 'mouseout') {  // type of event
    allColumn.removeClass('highlight');
  }
})
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: red;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1px solid black" class="data">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: where have you used `evtType`, other than declaration?

Comment: @Code_Ninja that also not required.Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: This is cool and it works with all other events like click. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you wouldn't be able to do what you are asking because the `this` in this instance is the object context of the exact element that triggered the mouse events.

If you were targeting a single element without the needing to know exactly which indexed item you were hovering over, then you could declare a variable in the scope higher than these two functions. However in this case you won't be able to declare `this` outside of the scope of these two functions and get the outcome you want.